# Prior distribution for Bayesian binary logistic regression

Tags: r, regression, bayesian

I am still quite new to regression models, but I am trying to apply a regression model to predict  victimization(0,1) in R given childhood experience. I have done many research but i still cannot find a suitable prior distribution to give us an informative(or at least weakly informative) prior. It is known that the observation for victimization is either 0 or 1, with a mean of 0.03441526.

Any input will be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you seen this https://github.com/stan-dev/stan/wiki/Prior-Choice-Recommendations

Comment: For other similar posts [see this list](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=logist*+baye*+prior*+weak*+infor*+answers%3A1)